# How do I use unfolded list values to specify a vertex?

Tags: java, groovy, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm trying to write a Gremlin traversal meaning "add all of these identities to this group", patterning it after [the "inject list" example in the recipes](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#long-traversals). This is the logic I'm attempting:

```
List identityIds = [...]

gts.inject(identityIds).unfold()
  .V() // filter statement goes here?
  .addE(GROUP_INCLUDES_IDENTITY).from(V(groupId))
  .iterate()
```

As I understand it, this will spawn a traverser for each element in the list and execute the `addE` operation. However, I can't figure out how to express `V().hasId(it)` in the traversal. The `identity()` step seems like it ought to be applicable, but I can't use it as an argument to either `V` or `hasId`.

I've tried to form an expression using `unfold().as("id")`, but I have the same problem that `select()` returns a traversal and I can't use a traversal in the obvious places.

Comment: if "identityIds" is just the id of the vertex then I'm not understanding the need to `inject()` - just pass the ids to `V()` like `g.V(identityIds)`

Comment: @stephenmallette I may be able to make that work, but this is a somewhat simplified example. Is there in fact a way to express "V where the ID is the value contained in the traverser"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where()` to do what you want:

```
gremlin> g.inject(1,2).as('id').
......1>   V().as('v').
......2>   where('id',eq('v')).
......3>     by().by(id)
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
```

but it's not ideal because it's unlikely that this traversal will get optimized to use an index.

I think that the best approach at this time is to use `V(identityIds)`. You allude to a more complex case and often times that complex case relates to wanting to pass additional data with the id (typically properties) in which case, I would still stick with `V(identityIds)` and simply treat that additional data as a side-effect:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> data = [[i: 1, w: 0.99],[i: 2, w: 0.98]]
==>[i:1,w:0.99]
==>[i:2,w:0.98]
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('d',data).
......1>   V(data.collect{it.i}).as('v').
......2>   addE('knows').to(V(6)).as('e').
......3>   select('d').unfold().as('p').
......4>   where('p',eq('v')).
......5>     by('i').by(id).as('weight').
......6>   select('e').
......7>   property('weight',select('weight'))
==>e[13][1-knows->6]
==>e[14][2-knows->6]
gremlin> g.E(13,14).elementMap()
==>[id:13,label:knows,IN:[id:6,label:person],OUT:[id:1,label:person],weight:[i:1,w:0.99]]
==>[id:14,label:knows,IN:[id:6,label:person],OUT:[id:2,label:person],weight:[i:2,w:0.98]]
```

There might be a nicer way to write that but the general idea is that you make sure you hit an index for the vertex lookup with `V(ids)` and then treat the data you want to use as some sort of side-effect which you have to match the vertex id to and then with the `Map` in hand you can update whatever properties you want. This [blog post](http://stephen.genoprime.com/snippet/2020/03/28/snippet-7.html) describes the general approach to this for inserts in greater detail.

Comment: The difficulty with the way you phrased this is that using the `{it.i}` lambda isn't portable. If I could say (I think) `__.select('i')`, then that would have the same semantics, but the type structure seems to artificially limit the expressiveness of what are isomorphic concepts.

Comment: the `{it.i}` part isn't relevant to the Gremlin. "data" is just a `List<Map>` and what that lambda demonstrates is the idea that you need to take "data" in whatever structure you have it and simply extract the ids to a `List` from each of those `Map` instances. It just so happens that `data.collect{it.i}` is the most convenient way to do that in groovy. In Java I suppose you might do: `data.stream().map(m => m.get('i')).collect(Collectors.toList())` - the point is that you use the same data source in the side-effect as you do to seed `V()` but seeding is not a function of Gremlin