# Why does my Gremlin traversal add only one edge?

Tags: java, groovy, gremlin, tinkerpop3

As described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65880973/1189885), I am attempting to add several "identity" vertices into a "group" vertex. Based on [the recipe recommendation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#long-traversals), I'm trying to write the traversal steps in such a way that the traversers iterate the identity vertices instead of appending extra steps in a loop. Here's what I have:

```
gts.V(group)
  .addE('includes')
  .to(V(identityIds as Object[]))
  .count().next()
```

This always returns a value of 1, no matter how many IDs I pass in `identityIds`, and only a single edge is created. The profile indicates that only a single traverser is created for the `__.V` even though I'm passing multiple values:

```
Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[849e1878-86ad-491e-b9f9...                     1           1           0.633    40.89
AddEdgeStep({label=[Includes], ~to=[[TinkerGrap...                     1           1           0.915    59.11
  TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[50d9bb4f-ed0d-493d-bf...                     1           1           0.135
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -           1.548        -
```

Why is only a single edge added to the first vertex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `to()` syntax you are using is not quite right. A modulator like `to()` expects the traversal you provide it to produce a single `Vertex` not a list. So, given `V(identityIds)` only the first vertex returned from that list of ids will be used to construct the edge. Step modulators like `to()`, `by()`, etc. tend to work like that.

You would want to reverse your approach to:

```
gts.V(identityIds)
  .addE('includes')
  .from(V(group))
  .count().next()
```

But perhaps that leads back to your other question.